# Good Custom View tutorials

Tags: android

So I want to create a view from scratch, I have a general idea on how to do it, but I would like to have some good reading on how to do it properly. Rather than reading the source code for a few days, I would like to find a good tutorial. The only ones I have located so far have been for extending subclasses of View, but I need to subclass View itself. If anyone knows of some good tutorials for this, some links would be  greatly  appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should start to read and understand this one:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html